# Typescript TypeORM ColumnTypeUndefinedError

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm, tsc

I tried TypeORM, and I got "ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for User#email is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported)."

The error wants me to add "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in tsconfig.json and import "reflect-metadata". I did both of them and still got this error. Could anyone give me some idea of what I should do for this error?

I have another minor error: my tsconfig.json file has "target": "ES6" and the compiled js files still have the es5 things. I feel like this minor error could be related to this ColumnTypeUndefinedError if my tsconfig.json file is doing nothing when compiling.

Here is the directory structure and code.

[image: directory structure]

typeorm.ts:

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection, createConnections, Connection } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./entity/User";

let connection;

const wrapper = async () => {
  connection = await createConnection({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "1234",
    database: "test",
    entities: [User],
  });
  await connection.connect();
};

wrapper();

console.log("abc");
```

entity/User.ts:

```js
import "reflect-metadata";

import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  CollectionAggregationOptions,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  college: string;
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES6"
  },
  "include": ["./typeorm.ts", "./entity/User.ts"]
}
```

typeorm.js:

```js
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
exports.__esModule = true;
require("reflect-metadata");
var typeorm_1 = require("typeorm");
var User_1 = require("./entity/User");
var connection;
var wrapper = function () { return __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function () {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, typeorm_1.createConnection({
                    type: "postgres",
                    host: "localhost",
                    port: 5432,
                    username: "postgres",
                    password: "jeong0422",
                    database: "test",
                    entities: [User_1.User]
                })];
            case 1:
                connection = _a.sent();
                return [4 /*yield*/, connection.connect()];
            case 2:
                _a.sent();
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}); };
wrapper();
console.log("abc");
```

User.js:

```js
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.User = void 0;
require("reflect-metadata");
var typeorm_1 = require("typeorm");
var User = /** @class */ (function () {
    function User() {
    }
    __decorate([
        typeorm_1.PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    ], User.prototype, "id");
    __decorate([
        typeorm_1.Column()
    ], User.prototype, "email");
    __decorate([
        typeorm_1.Column()
    ], User.prototype, "password");
    __decorate([
        typeorm_1.Column()
    ], User.prototype, "college");
    User = __decorate([
        typeorm_1.Entity()
    ], User);
    return User;
}());
exports.User = User;
```

Comment: i have the same problem and for me it is due to Babel or something. I don't get it.

Comment: have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//declare type in your columns like this
@Column({type:'varchar'})
  email: string
```